# How can implement and extend correctly in typescript?

Tags: typescript, oop

When I wrote OsProject and then student class extend from it I have to remove my initiation in student constructor and replace it with super() and also I have to add initializer to my property in student class. I think there is something wrong with my code because 3 argument in constructor are unuseful in this case and I can't understand it and also I can't understand what's the point with super in this case? Is it necessary? Totally when I have to use super?

```
interface Person{
    firstName: string;
    lastName : string;
    age: number;

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////
abstract class Project{
    projectName: string = "sds";
    budget: number = 1;

    calculateBudget(){
        return this.budget*2
    }
    abstract changeName(name: string): void
}

class OsProject extends Project{
     changeName(name: string){
         this.projectName = name
     }
}
 //////////////////////////////////////
 class Student extends OsProject implements Person{
     firstName: string = "x";
     lastName: string = "y";
     age: number = 1;
     constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number){
         super()
         //this.firstName = firstName;
         //this.lastName = lastName;
         //this.age = age;
     }
     print(){
         console.log(this.firstName)
     }
 }

 const myStudent:Student = new Student("x","y",22)
 myStudent.print()
```

Comment: "I have to remove my initiation in student constructor and replace it with super()".  Why do you "have to" do that?  What goes wrong [if you don't](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8zgN)?

Comment: Because without super I got error that it need call super and I think that when we have super we don't need initiation in constructor because we get them with super.

Comment: “  I think that when we have super we don't need initiation in constructor because we get them with super”. That’s not correct; why do you think that?  The call to `super()` initializes the superclass part of the instance but you still need to do any initialization of properties or state specific to the subclass.